# Flex and bison defining their own 'main' function

Tags: c, bison, ld, flex-lexer

Flex and bison define their own `main` function, so when I compile my code with the libraries `libfl` and `liby`, `ld` don't want to link it because `main` is declared multiple times. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libfl` and `liby` both define a `main` but if you use the invariant rule of always *putting libraries last* in the link command (or compile command if you are linking and compiling in one step) then they should not create any problems. (In other words, never put `-lfl -ly` *before* the object or source files you are linking.)

Note that you only need `libfl` if you don't either define or suppress `yywrap`. If you are using flex and you don't need the `yywrap` feature, add `%option noyywrap` to your flex input file and forget about `libfl`.

Furthermore, you should not require `liby` at all. In addition to `main`, it defines `yyerror`. However, you should always define `yyerror` yourself, so the library is totally unnecessary.

`libfl` and `liby` are "convenience" libraries which can help write quick and dirty tests or hacks. Production code should not rely on them. The functions they add comprise less than a dozen lines of not very useful code.

Comment: Note: as a result of the order of placing libraries last (and of the order of the libraries), the linker will search any next library for any symbols still unresolved. In other words, it uses the first occurrense of a symbol found. Putting the `main.c` with your `main` function first, will prevent the linker from searching for it in subsequent libraries (it will report any multiply defined symbols in all your source files though).